# Can I effectively utilise one layout for both a spinner and a listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-spinner, android-cursoradapter

The issue is I have is that rather than re-invent the anecdotal wheel; **I'd like to utilise the same layout for Spinners and also for ListViews, where the list will be based upon the same data.**

I also want a similar, custom, look throughout the App, such as lists (Spinners and ListViews) having alternating row colors and colors coded according to the current core activity ().

For example. My app has Shops (a core activity) which appear as a list in a `ListView` (ShopName, ShopCity and ShopOrder), the layout used for this is **`R.layout.shoplist`**, as per:

[image: ListView for Shops]

My app also has Aisles (another core activity, so colors are different). The list of Aisles is restricted to a one of the Shops, thus a Spinner is incorporated, listing the available Shops in order to select the respective Aisles. The Aisle list currently looks like, without a spinner :-

[image: ListView for Aisles without Spinner]

I know that I can just specify the ShopLIst Listview's Items layout for the spinner in the Spinner's Adapter simply by using the ShopList Adapter as per (where **sclcsr** is cusror containing all shops, and **selectshoplist** is the Spinner):-

```
        slcsr = dbshopmethods.getShops("", shopsorderby);
        selectshoplistadapter = new AdapterShopList(this,
                slcsr,
                CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER,
                getIntent(),
                true,
                false
        );
        selectshoplist.setAdapter(selectshoplistadapter);
```

*Note! there are 3 extra parameters than with a standard adapter, The `Intent` is passed (an `int` is extracted that is used to determine which range of colors is used, the first `boolean` is a flag to indicate a call from a `Spinner` as opposed to a `ListView`, the second is used to indicate whether or not to show extra data)*

However, the result is:-

[image: Aislelist with spinner directly using the Shoplist layout]

That is the customisation is lacking in the Spinner's dropdown list.

As such the question can now be **What do I need to do to set the background colours for the dropdown**?

Note I have a class (ActionColorCoding) and methodology for detremining/applying the colors in the adpater's **`getView`** method, as per :-

```
        int evenrow = ActionColorCoding.setHeadingColor(ctxt,
                callerintent,
                ActionColorCoding.getColorsPerGroup() - 1
                ) & ActionColorCoding.transparency_evenrow;
        int oddrow = evenrow & ActionColorCoding.transparency_oddrow;
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(evenrow);
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(oddrow);
        }
```

So the above would be the basis of the code to be incorporated into the adapter. Custimsation of the Spinnner's Selection/selected item is not an issue as this is as per the Spinner's declaration in the activity's layout.

***Note, the intention of this Question, is as a guide that may be of assistance to others for a technique that there doesn't appear to be an answer for***

Comment: give some minutes to others to reply :)

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo, as per the Note at the bottom. The answer is known. The question has been provided as a guide for others. Hence the use of the AskandAnswer option, available when asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spinner's actually have two layout's associated with them, the second layout being for the **DropDownView** and will invoke the method **`getDropDownView`**, if Overidden (whilst ListViews invoke the **`getView`** method).

One thing to note is that, if `getDropDownView` invoked then **`bindView`** is not invoked so you have to invoke it.

By adding the following to the `ListView` adapter your adapter will cater for the `ListView` and the `Spinner` :-

```
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
        super.getDropDownView(position, convertview, parent);
        View view = convertview;
        if (fromspinner) {
            int cpos = this.cursor.getPosition();
            view = View.inflate(ctxt,R.layout.shoplist,null);
            int evenrow = ActionColorCoding.setHeadingColor(ctxt,callerintent, ActionColorCoding.getColorsPerGroup() - 1) & ActionColorCoding.transparency_evenrow;
            int oddrow = evenrow & ActionColorCoding.transparency_oddrow;
            if (position % 2 == 0) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(evenrow);
            } else {
                view.setBackgroundColor(oddrow);
            }
            this.cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        }
        bindView(view, ctxt, this.cursor);
        return view;
    }
```

Note! I don't believe that the `**if (fromspinner)**` construct is required but has been included as a precautionary measure.

Additional Note, callng `super.getDropDownView(position, convertview, parent);` appears to not be required and is thus, probably best note done.

Note! **`ctxt`**, **`calleritent`**, **`fromspinner`** and **`cursor`** are set in the Adpater's constructor as per :-

```
AdapterShopList(Context context,Cursor csr, int flags, Intent intent, boolean fromspinner,boolean showdetails) {
        super(context, csr, 0);
        ctxt = context;
        callerintent = intent;
        this.fromspinner = fromspinner;
        this.cursor = csr;
        setShopOffsets(csr);
    }
```

The result you get is :-

[image]

Comment: Added an additional note re calling `super.getDropDownView` being superfluous.